# "get" call from jquery/ajax not retrieving output from php file on localhost

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to feed the output from a php file into a javascript variable. My code looks like this -

PHP file:

```
<?php
echo "Hello World!";
?>
```

HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var data_from_ajax;
            $.get('http://127.0.0.1/output.php', function(data) {
                data_from_ajax = data;
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I'm using python's SimpleHTTPServer for temporary testing. The error that returns from the script is **Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED**. What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**
So I replaced the url with http://127.0.0.1:8000/output.php, and now the error has disappeared. When I type that URL into chrome, the php file downloads to my computer. Now however, when I try console.log(data_from_ajax), it returns "undefined", and still nothing shows up on the page. What could be going wrong?

Comment: Can you open that url in browser address bar?

Comment: @charlietfl Initially, that URL didn't open. After I added the port number however, it opens. See my edit

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to log outside of the `$.get` callback..before request completes. Ajax is asynchronous. Put the console.log() inside request callback

Comment: See: [how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @charlietfl Alright, so now it prints the contents of output.php. But it is printing <?php echo "Hello World!"; ?> rather than just "Hello World". How do I fix this?

Comment: Your `SimpleHTTPServer` isn't set up to compile php. Need to install something like XAMPP that includes and runs php

Comment: I used mac's built-in PHP development server. It worked, thank you so much! @charlietfl

Comment: ok...that was simple. `$.get` working now?

Comment: Is your problem solved? @RushilJoshi

Comment: @charlietfl yep, everything is working now. Thanks!